# DB non-clustered Index on event log date DESC a bad idea?

Tags: database, indexing

We have a SQL table that is populated with events from our website (mostly error logging and the like.)  The table has several text fields that contain all of the information about the type of event, and a date/time field that shows when the event was logged.  The table is fairly large and grows by around 10-100 records per day.

Obviously, when going through this log, we often are looking for the most recent items, so I figured an obvious way to improve our search times would be to add a index to the date field.  Me, I figured that while either ASC or DESC would both be great, DESC would be better since that's the way we're searching most of the time.  Our DB guy said "no way"...it would be really bad, because the index table would rapidly become fragmented.

I could see why you wouldn't want to have a clustered index on date DESC, because you'd constantly be trying to insert at the beginning...but I thought with a non-clustered index it would be okay, since the records wouldn't need to be moved around.  But what he's saying also makes sense...still would have to move indexes around.

But how much?  And how big of a hit would it be?  And even if it isn't much of a hit, maybe it's still not worth it because the performance on occasional selects just couldn't improve that much?  Thoughts?

Comment: What is this "SQL table" of which you speak? Is this a new invention?

Comment: @cagcowboy: I specifically didn't say, because I was hoping it didn't matter...I'm assuming, perhaps naively, that indexing will be fairly similar across systems.  It would be interesting to know if that's not the case.  (For us, we're using SQL Server, but for other people that search and find this answer, I'd like to see possible answers for other systems, if they're different.)

Comment: @skaffman: Well, it's nothing built in, if that's what you mean.  But it doesn't really matter...for the question, it's just a table in the database that has at least two fields...one that has the textual data in it that the developer wants to read, and the other that has a date/time.  But a potential important aspect is that the records will always be entered in chronological order...which is why clustered indexing on the date decending would seem to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a bad idea - quite the contrary!

Not knowing your database system, I can't really be sure why your DB guy would think this would be a bad idea. And even so - even an ascending index on the date will be quite beneficial already (at least in the case of SQL Server).

In this case, if you do frequently query by date and usually will retrieve the most recent ones, this seems like a perfect index to me! Maybe you could make it even better by adding the second most likely selection criteria (log application? log type?) to it, so that if you specify both the date and that second criteria, the search scope would be even more limited within the index.

If I were you, I would try a few sample queries against the table without this index, and then add the non-clustered index on your logdate - first with ASC and test how your queries perform (check out their execution plans!), then try the index with DESC, and possibly try the index with LogDate and an additional criteria field, too. See how performance looks like.

Marc

Comment: Makes sense...and we've done this to some extent, and (not surprisingly) you're quite right: either index improves the speed considerably.  But what isn't obvious (to me) is whether the index would be fragmented by constantly trying to add records in chronological order, but having the index trying to do the exact reverse.  In a very hand-wavey way, I want to say "well, gosh, this is what indexes are good at...even if this is a worst case scenario, it's not all that bad."  But I'd like some way to *know*.

Comment: Sure - I'll try to find a definite answer to that. For the time being, I'd suggest creating and using at least the LogDate ASC index in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes speed up some queries but slow down all loads. Whether or not an index gives an overall performance improvement depends on how much it speeds up your actual query workload and how much it slows down your actual loading workload (as well as deletes and updates that modify the indexed column).

In many (probably most) applications that involve storing event data, there is a huge amount of loading going on and relatively little querying, which is primarily summary-type queries that don't benefit from indexes. In these sorts of applications, indexes often do more harm than good.

In many such applications, it is possible to do loads during off hours so even if the index gives an overall slowdown, it might be worth it to increase query speed because someone is waiting for the query output but no one waits for the load to complete. However, the index can get so large that overruns the file cache and each insert has to read and write a different leaf page from disk. At this point, loads start to require a linear number of random access disk reads and writes, which can cause it to take all day to do a load.